# How to capture the image from Canon Digital Camera IXUS 75 Video mode

Tags: camera, capture, wia

I trying capturing the image in video mode from Canon Digital Camera IXUS 75 model using WIA type. But I didn't get any thing. If Photo mode, I can seen digital Camera storage data i.e., video,photos etc. So, is it required any .dll file or any stuff for capturing image in video mode. Even I tried different way's also

1. Using JavaCV.It detects Webcam,Laptop internal Camera.But it doesn't detect digital Camera device.
2. JTWAIN is not supported with windows 64-bit OS. So, I didn't tried with this.

Please help me. Either Canon digital camera software nor Java relevant stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you still plan to use Java and if the problem is still an issue, I used Asprise's JTwain to get image from scanner, camera (not only laptop web cam) and etc. The only thing you need are the drivers for the devices. Grab an eval version from Asprise and check this step by step dev guide [here](http://asprise.com/product/jtwain/AspriseJTwain-DevGuide.pdf). As far as I understood, this should be good enough for your requirements.

By the way, seeing the file structure of a camera does not always mean you have the device fully working.